# Creating a RDF in Jython

Tags: database, jython, rdf, sparql

How do we create RDF database in Jython? I use this to implement SparQL in Jython. So I need to create the database first.

Answer (score 3):

See [RDFAlchemyJython](http://www.openvest.com/trac/wiki/RDFAlchemyJython) for reusing most well known Java tools for RDF and SPARQL  in Jython; or go for [RDFLIB](http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/), a wide spread RDF and SPARQL framework for Python.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say use the Jena libs, but msalvadores got there already, check the RDFAlchemyJython link. I'll add that it is pretty straightforward, just use them like you would any other Java libs in Jython.

TDB is probably the best bet for a SPARQLable database, see:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/java_api.html

Just put the libs on your classpath, tweak the code to be js not Java.